# About Ms Sql Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a trigger to change the values of `BarcodeFormat` column.

So I made a trigger, but I am not sure if it works.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE trigger tr_changedUPC
on Item
after update
as update Item
SET BarcodeFormat=(case when(ISNUMERIC(ItemLookupCode)=1) AND
(LEN(ItemLookupCode)=12) AND (NOT(BarcodeFormat=9)) then 9 else 6 end) from inserted
```

As you can see, I am making a trigger on item Table. When the value of column `Item.ItemLookupCode` changes, I want to change the value of column `Item.BarcodeFormat`, too.

I didn't execute this SQL code yet. So I want you to see this code if it is good.

Comment: So are you asking if this code is good, without executing it first? Give us your definition of 'good code'. Readable? Re-usable? Executable without errors? Anyway, how a person could know if a code is good, without, for example measuring the seconds involved in the creation and execution of this trigger?

Comment: Executable without errors

Answer (score 1):

According to this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=6/cafba/1#!6/61302/1),

```
CREATE trigger tr_changedUPC
on Item
after update
as update Item
SET BarcodeFormat=(case when(ISNUMERIC(ItemLookupCode)=1) AND
(LEN(ItemLookupCode)=12) AND (NOT(BarcodeFormat=9)) then 9 else 6 end) from inserted
```

your code should be a little improved in this way, to make columns less ambiguous:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_changedUPC
    on Item
    after UPDATE
    as UPDATE Item
    SET Item.BarcodeFormat=(case when(ISNUMERIC(Item.ItemLookupCode)=1) AND
    (LEN(Item.ItemLookupCode)=12) AND (NOT(Item.BarcodeFormat=9)) then 9 else 6 end) from inserted;
```

Your code is fine, according to the results of the fiddle, because the values of column 'BarCodeFormat' are updated accordingly with the update of column 'ItemLookupCode'.

Comment: @user2682815 You're welcome. If the answer is correct for you, check the mark at the left to accept it. ;)